# Commenting xml file using shell script

Tags: unix

I have an input xml file like below :-

INPUT FILE

```
<operand> Total Deep </operand>
<operand> Total Saurav </operand>
```

I want to comment out the tag which contains Total Deep. My output file will look like this. Please not the xml file contains many operands. The below is just an example.

OUTPUT FILE

```
<!--<operand> Total Deep </operand>-->
<operand> Total Saurav </operand>
```

My Code

```
sed '/<operand>/s/^/<--/;/<\/operand>/s/$/-->/' inputfile > outputfile
```

While executing the code i am getting below exception

```
sed : -e expression #1, char 24: unknown command: `o'
```

Can anyone help me out on this??

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/<operand> Total Deep <\/operand>/{s/^/<!--/;s/$/-->/}' inputfile > outputfile
```

As you have "/" in the search html syntax, the first thing you will need to do is escape this when searching for "...Total Deep....". You then want to execute two sed commands on the search result and so place them in { .... }